# What type of attacks does HTTPS protect against?

Tags: tls, http, man-in-the-middle

What are some example attacks that could be vulnerable if HTTP is used, and that can be overcome in HTTPS? The only one I can think of is man in the middle attacks, where the intercepted traffic is in plain text. What are some others?

Also are on-path attacks and man in the middle attacks the same thing?

Comment: With HTTP, it's possible for anyone who is in a position to monitor the traffic as it goes over the network to view the unencrypted content, simply through passive eavesdropping.  With HTTPS, it's not enough to simply monitor the traffic, the connection must be actively man-in-the-middle'd in order for an attacker to view the traffic.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66310/whats-the-difference-between-mitm-attack-and-sniffing for the difference between the two types of attacks.

Comment: Passwords in forms and HTTP basic authentication would be very easy to eavesdrop, credit card numbers etc. etc., anything filled into a form. Note that HTTPS also provides entity authentication of the server (client authentication can be included or performed after the secure channel has been effectuated).

Comment: Have you looked this up? Done any research? Hundreds of sites over decades have explained the various things that HTTPS protects against.

Comment: I agree with @schroeder, it looks like OP did little to no research on the question.

Answer (score 1):

TLS, which is what's used to secure HTTPS, provides three things: confidentiality, integrity, and authentication.  Confidentiality means that the data is hidden from an attacker, integrity means that the data is not modified, and authentication means that the remote party is the expected party.

While most of these attacks do require a party to be somewhere on the same network (and therefore perform a MITM attack), that is not necessarily a problem.  For example, Southwest has been known to inject a banner into HTTP pages on its in-flight Wi-Fi, and Verizon injects an advertising header.  These are cases where integrity is a valuable feature.

Confidentiality is the critical feature if you're sending or receiving secrets, such as a password, a credit card number, or medical information, or even if you just don't want your ISP snooping on what you're looking at on Wikipedia.  As Phil Zimmerman said, “It’s personal.  It’s private.  And it’s nobody’s business but yours.”

Authenticity is helpful because it makes sure that the site you're talking to is really the same site, and that an attacker has not somehow managed to redirect your traffic elsewhere.  So if you're on a Wi-Fi network in a coffee shop and someone redirects your traffic to their system, they can’t pretend to be a legitimate website to snoop your traffic.

All of these are desirable features.  Most modern versions of TLS also provide what's called *forward secrecy* if configured properly, which essentially means that once the connection is done, as long as both sides discard the secrets they used to create it and the keys that were generated as part of the session, nobody, not even the original participants, can recover the encrypted session.  This means that if one of the participants (e.g., the website you visited) is later compromised, the encrypted data remains secret.

But yes, to answer your question, most of these attacks require someone to be on the same network, so either a passive eavesdropper, or an active MITM attacker.  As mentioned, if you ever use an untrusted Wi-Fi network or a network run by a major corporation, you're vulnerable.  Forward secrecy also protects against later compromises that happen outside of a MITM attack.